# How some media players play wma on Android

Tags: java, android, wmv, wma

I was writing code for a media player and learned that Android doesn't support wma/wmv format but how come there are some players on the Play Store which can actually play wma.

I downloaded one and checked on my phone and it worked.

I am really puzzled how these people have managed to do this?

Please help me in understanding on how tos??

Hope I will also include .wma format in my player as well.

Thanks!

Comment: have you got any valuable solutions?

Answer (score 2):

They wrote their own decoder.  [WMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Audio) is microsoft's proprietary media format.  So it makes sense that Android wouldn't support it.  The people who support this format reverse-engineered the WMA codecs.